# How do I get the webcam working on a Dell Vostro 3460?

Tags: webcam, google-talk, dell-vostro

The webcam is properly detected on **Ubuntu 12.10**, but I cannot make it work with **Google Talk** 3.2.4... No problem with Skype though.

`xinput` shows a `Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_E4HD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the Google talk plugin installed

For 32-bit Ubuntu try:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0
sudo mv /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin.real
echo '#!/bin/sh' | sudo tee /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
echo "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin.real" | sudo tee -a /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
sudo chmod +x /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
```

For 64-bit Ubuntu try:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32v4l-0
sudo mv /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin.real
echo '#!/bin/sh' | sudo tee /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
echo "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin.real" | sudo tee -a /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
sudo chmod +x /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
```

Repeat when you install a new version of the Google Talk plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot! After setting `LD_PRELOAD`, _Verify your settings_ fails to load the camera sometimes; but this is definitely a big progress! It also fails occasionally when I capture video with `avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0`.

Comment: Also you could try opening a terminal and running `gstreamer-properties` and then going to the video tab. Go under **Default Input** and select the _Video for Linux 2 (v4l2)_ plugin if it is not already selected, then on **Device** select _Intergrated Camera_ or whatever option other than default you have, then hit test and close.

Comment: Thanks again. The behavior is a bit random, but I managed to see the video working on Google Talk without the wrapper around GoogleTalkPlugin when I set the **Device** in `gstreamer-properties`.